# Could not post to server using volley

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I've tried a lot of tutorial to post to the server, but nothing happened, when I tried in postman, it worked well, but when I tested in android, it didn't work.

Here are my java method

```
private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ApiService.login, response -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response);
            hideDialog();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    String uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
                    JSONObject user = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user");
                    String username1 = user.getString("username");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String city = user.getString("city");
                    String subdistrict = user.getString("subdistrict");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String nickname = user.getString("nickname");
                    String address = user.getString("address");
                    String phone = user.getString("phone");
                    String birth_date = user.getString("birth_date");
                    String gender = user.getString("gender");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");
                    String updated_at = user.getString("updated_at");
                    String weight = user.getString("weight");
                    String height = user.getString("height");
                    String prohibition = user.getString("prohibition");

                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Successfully logged in, congrats!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(uid, username1, email, city, subdistrict, name, nickname, address, phone, birth_date, gender, created_at, updated_at);
                    db.updateMedicalInfo(weight, height, prohibition, updated_at);
                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login_view. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jsonObject.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }, error -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login_view url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
    }
```

And here my php code

```
<?php
// Request type is check Login
define('root', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); 
    require_once(root.'\dion\api\function\AuthFunctions.php'); 
    $db = new AuthFunctions();
    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);
        if (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])) {
            // receiving the post params
            // menangkap data yang dikirimkan sebelumnya -> POST
            $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
            $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
            // get the user by email and password
            // menangkap data yang dikirimkan sebelumnya -> POST
            $user = $db->getUserByUsernameAndPassword($username, $password);
            if ($user != false) {
                // use is found
                // jika user telah ditemukan dan cocok pada database, maka akan dimunculkan data user
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["city"] = $user["city"];
                $response["user"]["subdistrict"] = $user["subdistrict"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["nickname"] = $user["nickname"];
                $response["user"]["address"] = $user["address"];
                $response["user"]["phone"] = $user["phone"];
                $response["user"]["birth_date"] = $user["birth_date"];
                $response["user"]["gender"] = $user["gender"];
                $response["user"]["weight"] = $user["weight"];
                $response["user"]["height"] = $user["height"];
                $response['user']['prohibition'] = $user['prohibition'];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                // ditampilkan dalam bentuk json 
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user is not found with the credentials
                // jika user tidak ditemukan maka akan muncul pesan 
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Login not matched. Please try again!";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else {
            // required post params is missing
            // jika tidak ada inputan untuk login
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        ?>
```

When I used postman, I got my json response as I want like this [Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGaHv.png)
But when I tried in android, it says there's no parameter sent.

Comment: Add logs. What is response? First you need to understand is it on request side or after request sent on server side and after that analyze what response you receive from server, Make separation on 3 separate actions and with help of debugger you will find where issue is.

Comment: I've fixed this stuff bro, thanks for your comment I really appreciate it @BorisRuzanov